# Parallel calls $.when with $.ajax() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to make parallel calls using the jQuery method $.when

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sample Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $.when(
            // Get the first call
            $.ajax("delay_test.php"),

            // Get the second call
            $.ajax("delay_test.php")
        ).then(function(first,second) {
            $("body").append("Done: "+first[0]+"<br>Done: "+second[0]);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I made also a php code for test this and see if it was really avoiding make the second call after the first one had finished.

```
<?php
    sleep(5);
    echo date("H:i:s");
?>
```

But what I am receiving is the 5 seconds difference:

```
Done: 15:27:55
Done: 15:28:00
```

Is there something I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Comment: Hard to interpret what you say you are receiving. Can you provide what you actually are seeing? And what your expectations are. Both requests will be made immediately and execute separate instances of the php script

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see what the browser is actually sending and what the server is actually returning.  You need to figure out if this is a server issue or a client issue.  Also, watch out for browser caching since you're sending the exact same request.  And, what version of jQuery are you using?  `.then()` and `.done()` are going to have somewhat different behaviors in jQuery 3.x because `.then()` is changing to be standard ES6 promise behavior which jQuery did not follow in jQuery 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: What exact results are you seeing?  Please show us exactly what you receive.

Comment: Updated, I am seeing what I am appending into the body

Comment: If your PHP server is not multi-threaded, then the second request can't be served until the first one is done, thus a delta of `5` seconds between results.  You'd probably have to explain a lot more about how your PHP server is configured and set up.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I am using chrome, I'm not able right now to test in other browsers :(

Comment: Try opening Dev Tools, go to network tab, and disable cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let me say you can resolve your issue by using `cache:false` with your AJAX requests:

```
$.when(
  // Get the first call
  $.ajax({url:"delay.php",cache:false}),
  // Get the second call
  $.ajax({url:"delay.php",cache:false})
).then(function(first,second) {
  $("body").append("Done: "+first[0]+"<br>Done: "+second[0]);
});
```

Now let me expand by saying I'm not quite sure why. Something about chrome awaiting the result of the first AJAX request to send the second; perhaps waiting to see if it should pull the result from cache. Perhaps someone more enlightened with Chrome could say why. I did not have the issue in IE 11, and I did not test FireFox, Safari, Opera, etc.

Alternatively, you can append a GET variable to the end of the URL if you don't want to use an object and define `url` and `cache` (the `cache:false` option just appends a timestamp to the URLs to make them unique). Something like:

```
$.when(
  // Get the first call
  $.ajax("delay.php?r1"),
  // Get the second call
  $.ajax("delay.php?r2")
).then(function(first,second) {
  $("body").append("Done: "+first[0]+"<br>Done: "+second[0]);
});
```

<del>Edit: Another alternative is to set no-cache headers in your PHP script. If you use this method, you'll likely have to clear your cache first, as your browser probably cached it already:</del>

<del>`header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");`</del>
    <del>`header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);`</del>
    <del>`header("Pragma: no-cache");`</del>

Nevermind the above suggestion - didn't work in my testing.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested too. It works with first two options.